# When I try to set a clickListener, app crashes

Tags: java, android, button, multidimensional-array, onclicklistener

Every time I run this app on my emulator, the app crashes when I tap the play button:

```
public class PixelCheckActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pixel_check);
    final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    // ...40 b's defined here ex: final Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    final Button[][] arr = {
            {b1,b2,b3,b4,b5},
            {b6,b7,b8,b9,b10},
            {b11,b12,b13,b14,b15},
            {b16,b17,b18,b19,b20},
            {b21,b22,b23,b24,b25},
            {b26,b27,b28,b29,b30},
            {b31,b32,b33,b34,b35},
            {b36,b37,b38,b39,b40}
    };
    final View.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.pixel_tap_game);
            final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);}
            };
            for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){arr[0][i].setOnClickListener(listener);}
        }
    };
    play.setOnClickListener(listener1);
}
}
```

I think the problem is, the 40 b's are in a different layout file then the play button.
So, what do I need to do in order to fix this?

Here is the Logcat crash log:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ry1T.png

Comment: Can you give us more details? Post your Logcat or something relevant. It could be the Button play that is null. Please give more details.

Comment: Please share the crash logs.

Comment: have you initialize arr[][] buttons ?

Comment: I will as soon as possible.

Comment: I can't seem to run the app now (Gradle sync error), but the Log cat said something about a 'null pointer'. However the problem has been solved. Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 40 buttons are in a different layout, if they are not in the layout you inflated in your activity (`R.layout.activity_pixel_check`), then you can't get a reference through `findViewById` method. The `findViewById` will return a view reference **IF it's in the activity's layout**, or **null if not**. So you will have an array of 40 null references, and when you call `arr[0][i].setOnClickListener(listener)` you surely get a NullPointerException

Comment: Then do I need to initialize the 40 buttons after the button is clicked? If so how?

Comment: Initialize buttons after setContentView(R.layout.pixel_tap_game). However I would suggest you to use two Activities, one with play button and one with the 40 buttons, changing activity's layout is not the normal android programming.Write into the listener1 onClick: startActivity(new Intent(PixelCheckAcrivity.this, ButtonsActivity.class)), where ButtonsActivity will be an other Activity with layout R.layout.pixel_tap_game

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I do not know if it works yet (due to gradle file syncing error), but according to the Logcat errors I was getting your solution should work :) Thanks!